# Android multiple root tags

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to android development and I don't know if the answer is obvious but help would be much appreciated!Here's the code:

```
<fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:name="com.example.jessica valdez.zen.NavigationDrawerFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Please give the error log.

Comment: It's not code, it's data.  You should learn the basics of XML first.

Comment: Show your complete XML, there might be you are adding root tag twice :)